How do I retrieve Sharing Hierarchy data for any record in APEX?
I've a necessity to create a view similar to Sharing Hierarchy view of Salesforce for any Record.
I thought it would be kind of easy as I may just need to query the CustomObj__Share object (given that my object is a Custom Object.
So I ran my SOQL like this:
SELECT AccessLevel, RowCause, UserOrGroup.Name FROM CustomObj__Share WHERE ParentId = 'a0l5g000000t2qf'

The query ran correctly but only given 2 records:

One for the user who is the owner of the record.
Second for the Public Group who is manually added to the record sharing.

Now, the data however is correct, but when I use the Standard Sharing Hierarchy button to load the view it shows more than 10 users in the initial grid, and each user has a View link that open Access Details of the user with more rows/details.
Why does my data differ and how can I get the full view similar to that standard Sharing Hierarchy view in a custom way like APEX/LWC?

why not just redirect to the OOTB URL that does this?

It's part of a complex component where hierarchy is just a view within. it can't be redirect.

From the documentation "Sharing a Record Using Apex":

Sharing that is granted to users implicitly through organization-wide defaults, the role hierarchy, and permissions such as the “View All” and “Modify All” permissions for the given object, “View All Data,” and “Modify All Data” aren’t tracked with this object.

This implies, for example: If CustomObj is shared with me and "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" checked, in one go all my superiors turn up in the "Sharing Hierarchy". But they don't get their own CustomObj__Share records.
Below an Apex class that retrieved the role based sharing for the record I experimented with.
public without sharing class SharingHierarchyManager {

    private Map<Id, Id> role2parent = new Map<Id, Id>();
    private Map<Id, User> userId2user = new Map<Id, User>();
    private Map<Id, List<User>> roleId2users 
        = new Map<Id, List<User>>();

    public SharingHierarchyManager() {
        List<User> users = [
            SELECT Name, UserRoleId FROM User 
            WHERE IsActive = TRUE ORDER BY Name];
        List<UserRole> userRoles = [
            SELECT ParentRoleId FROM UserRole];

        for(UserRole role : userRoles) {
            role2parent.put(role.Id, role.ParentRoleId);
        }
        
        userId2user = new Map<Id, User>(users);
        for(User u : users) {
            if(u.UserRoleId == null) continue;
            if(!roleId2users.containsKey(u.UserRoleId)) {
                roleId2users.put(u.UserRoleId, new List<User>());
            }
            roleId2users.get(u.UserRoleId).add(u);
        }
    }
    
    // E.g. call with Schema.CustomObj__Share.SObjectType
    public void process(SObjectType sot, Id recordId) {
        
        // TODO: AccessLevel are overwritten by lower one's
        Map<Id, String> userResults = new Map<Id, String>();
        // TODO: Group IDs are ignored
        Map<Id, String> groupResults = new Map<Id, String>();

        populateFromShares(sot, recordId, userResults, groupResults);
        Map<Id, String> userIdsOfParentRoles 
            = populateRoleHierarchy(userResults);
        userResults.putAll(userIdsOfParentRoles);
        
        print(userResults, userId2user);
    }

    private Map<Id, String> populateRoleHierarchy(Map<Id, String> userResults) {
        Map<Id, String> userIdsOfParentRoles = new Map<Id, String>();
        for(Id userId : userResults.keySet()) {
            Map<Id, String> roleParentUsers 
                = getRoleParentUsers(userId, userResults.get(userId));
            userIdsOfParentRoles.putAll(roleParentUsers);
        }
        return userIdsOfParentRoles;
    }

    private void populateFromShares(SObjectType sot, Id recordId, Map<Id, String> userResults, Map<Id, String> groupResults) {
        String query = 'SELECT AccessLevel, RowCause, UserOrGroup.Name '
            + 'FROM ' + sot.getDescribe().getName() + ' '
            + 'WHERE ParentId =: recordId';
        List<SObject> shares = Database.query(query);

        for(SObject sh : shares) {
            Id userOrGroupId = (Id) sh.get('UserOrGroupId');
            if(userOrGroupId.getSobjectType() == Schema.User.SObjectType) {
                userResults.put(userOrGroupId, (String) sh.get('AccessLevel'));
            } else {
                groupResults.put(userOrGroupId, (String) sh.get('AccessLevel'));
            }
        }
    }
    
    private Map<Id, String> getRoleParentUsers(Id userId, String accessLevel) {
        
        Map<Id, String> userResults = new Map<Id, String>();
        userResults.put(userId, accessLevel);
        Id roleId = userId2user.get(userId).UserRoleId;
        while(roleId != null) {
            roleId = role2parent.get(roleId);
            List<User> users = roleId2users.get(roleId);
            if(users == null) continue;
            for(User u : users) {
                userResults.put(u.Id, accessLevel);
            }
        }
        
        return userResults;
    }

    private static void print(Map<Id, String> userResults, 
                            Map<Id, User> userId2user) {
        for(Id userId : userResults.keySet()) {
            System.debug(userId2user.get(userId).Name + ': ' 
                         + userResults.get(userId));
        }
    }
}

E.g. call...
new SharingHierarchyManager().process(
    Schema.CustomObj__Share.SObjectType, recordId);

and have a look at debug output.
But if we want to mirror everything that appears in the Sharing Hierarchy, this is just a start. Here's the list of types of "Shares" that I can create on my org:

User
Customer Portal User
Portal Role
Portal Role and Subordinates
Public Group
Role
Role and Internal Subordinates
Role, Internal and Portal Subordinates

Clearly, above Apex is not even half way :-)

Many thanks for your efforts to explain this. I was hoping there should be simpler way to just find out all users with access to a record, but UserRecordAccess object only allows to query by 1 single user, which is troublesome if there are 1000+ users in org.

Someone shares your sentiment ;-) One might wonder, if Salesforce internally doesn't already have some "bulkified" version of this.

Extending on to this. Can you help me guide if I were not to consider bulkify operation but instead look to find how a single user has been granted access to the record like finding out the reason. for example, it may be a case where user may be given Edit permission from some criteria and user may be part of multiple groups which give different access, I would like to list all the reasons for the access. possible much?

Even if the question is narrowed to "Why does this particular user have access to this particular record?", I don't see how this can be answered without writing logic like the one above for walking up the Role hierarchy. Similar would need to be written for Sharing records that grant access due to "Subordinates". More logic would need to be written for OWD, Sharing records that grant access based on groups, Restriction Rules etc. There might already be a package on AppExchange.
